# Modifying a MultiPolygon with Openlayers when two subpolygons share sides or vertices

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-8

I'm hoping to be able to modify a MultiPolygon in Openlayers that consists of several sub-polygons. I've activated the standard Modify-interaction, and dragging both vertices and creating new line segments when dragging on the line works fine. However, it seems that it is inconsistent when it comes to the edit operation.

The behaviour is very inconsice. For some vertices, it will drag all connected vertices (desired behaviour) like this:
[image: Desired behaviour]

For other locations, it will drag only some, but not all vertices:
[image: Bad behaviour]

It will not (always, but sometimes) modify both sub-entities when dragging to add new segments:
[image: Inserting new vertices]

This is code to reproduce the unexpected behaviour:

```js
var multiPolygon = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "1.1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              1193836.0495014254,
              8383930.129123866
            ],
            [
              1193847.7380479588,
              8383914.044627354
            ],
            [
              1193861.7086440534,
              8383894.250081073
            ],
            [
              1193873.9649199897,
              8383877.232589948
            ],
            [
              1193883.717211206,
              8383863.628916129
            ],
            [
              1193894.5047360454,
              8383944.666907605
            ],
            [
              1193881.5012495161,
              8383963.164657038
            ],
            [
              1193860.4841296545,
              8383947.813224077
            ],
            [
              1193843.674886545,
              8383935.594306091
            ],
            [
              1193836.0495014254,
              8383930.129123866
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "2.1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              1193883.717211206,
              8383863.628916128
            ],
            [
              1193889.0153151448,
              8383856.238480768
            ],
            [
              1193890.5403921688,
              8383857.260414857
            ],
            [
              1193909.1752749276,
              8383870.745514915
            ],
            [
              1193929.301838863,
              8383884.8526888145
            ],
            [
              1193934.6451744211,
              8383888.740497403
            ],
            [
              1193929.168255474,
              8383896.316176012
            ],
            [
              1193903.787411573,
              8383931.462094758
            ],
            [
              1193894.5047360454,
              8383944.666907605
            ],
            [
              1193883.717211206,
              8383863.628916128
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

const styleFunction = () => {
  const style = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.4)',
        width: 2,
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: `rgba(0,0,255,0.2)`,
      }),
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 3,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.4)',
        }),
      }),
      geometry: function(feature) {
        // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
        const type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
        let coordinates;
        if (type === 'Polygon') {
          coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
        } else if (type === 'MultiPolygon') {
          const coordArray = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
          coordinates = [];
          coordArray.forEach((ring) => {
            coordinates.push(...ring[0]);
          });
        }
        return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(coordinates);
      },
    }),
  ];
  return style;
};

var multiPolygonFeatures = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(multiPolygon);
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: multiPolygonFeatures,
});

var viewCenter = [1193887, 8383870];
var view = new ol.View({
  projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  center: viewCenter,
  zoom: 18,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: styleFunction
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view,
});


const modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  source: vectorSource
});
map.addInteraction(modify);
```

```css
html,
body,
.map {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ol-dragbox {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-color: rgba(100, 150, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one of the coordinates was an exact match between both polygons, The other differed in the last digit.

The Modify interaction will update one coordinate of each geometry at the same position. (There was a bug in older versions of OpenLayers where multiple coordinates of the same geometry were modified when they were the same. You may want to use the latest version in that case.)

Here is the updated example:

```js
var multiPolygon = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "1.1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              1193836.0495014254,
              8383930.129123866
            ],
            [
              1193847.7380479588,
              8383914.044627354
            ],
            [
              1193861.7086440534,
              8383894.250081073
            ],
            [
              1193873.9649199897,
              8383877.232589948
            ],
            [
              1193883.717211206,
              8383863.628916129
            ],
            [
              1193894.5047360454,
              8383944.666907605
            ],
            [
              1193881.5012495161,
              8383963.164657038
            ],
            [
              1193860.4841296545,
              8383947.813224077
            ],
            [
              1193843.674886545,
              8383935.594306091
            ],
            [
              1193836.0495014254,
              8383930.129123866
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "2.1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              1193883.717211206,
              8383863.628916129
            ],
            [
              1193889.0153151448,
              8383856.238480768
            ],
            [
              1193890.5403921688,
              8383857.260414857
            ],
            [
              1193909.1752749276,
              8383870.745514915
            ],
            [
              1193929.301838863,
              8383884.8526888145
            ],
            [
              1193934.6451744211,
              8383888.740497403
            ],
            [
              1193929.168255474,
              8383896.316176012
            ],
            [
              1193903.787411573,
              8383931.462094758
            ],
            [
              1193894.5047360454,
              8383944.666907605
            ],
            [
              1193883.717211206,
              8383863.628916129
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

const styleFunction = () => {
  const style = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.4)',
        width: 2,
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: `rgba(0,0,255,0.2)`,
      }),
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 3,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.4)',
        }),
      }),
      geometry: function(feature) {
        // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
        const type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
        let coordinates;
        if (type === 'Polygon') {
          coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
        } else if (type === 'MultiPolygon') {
          const coordArray = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
          coordinates = [];
          coordArray.forEach((ring) => {
            coordinates.push(...ring[0]);
          });
        }
        return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(coordinates);
      },
    }),
  ];
  return style;
};

var multiPolygonFeatures = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(multiPolygon);
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: multiPolygonFeatures,
});

var viewCenter = [1193887, 8383870];
var view = new ol.View({
  projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  center: viewCenter,
  zoom: 18,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: styleFunction
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view,
});


const modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  source: vectorSource
});
map.addInteraction(modify);
```

```css
html,
body,
.map {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ol-dragbox {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-color: rgba(100, 150, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After detailed inspection of the raw data (the polygon data), I've come to understand that the modify interaction requires the polygon vertices to share the exact same coordinate (even down to the tenth decimal) in order for it to trigger the shared editing. I believed that the snapping would detect such minor differences. I was apparently wrong in that assumption.

In my code above, those vertices who did not work with shared editing had the last digit different.

By changing how the source (the GeoJSON) is generated, and adding some rounding to it, it works as desired.